# Tried changing to static ip in RedHat 6.5 using VMWare. Unable to access the internet now

Tags: networking, rhel, ip, internet

I followed resources on the internet to assign static ip address for RedHat 6.5 installation in VMWare. I am unable to access the internet after that. My terminal output of the files I changed are as folows:

```
[Piyush@redhatcdh4_1 ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=00:0C:29:BE:52:B7
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=8bd6e426-9bad-4f0c-a098-9345e1d51bfa
ONBOOT=no
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.31.217
NETMASK=255.255.255.0

[Piyush@redhatcdh4_1 ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=redhatcdh4_1
GATEWAY=192.168.31.2
NTPSERVERARGS=iburst
```

The output of the ifconfig command is as follows:

```
[Piyush@redhatcdh4_1 ~]$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:BE:52:B7  
          inet addr:192.168.31.217  Bcast:192.168.31.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:febe:52b7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3611 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:226739 (221.4 KiB)  TX bytes:636 (636.0 b)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:601 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:601 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:46796 (45.6 KiB)  TX bytes:46796 (45.6 KiB)
```

.

```
[Piyush@redhatcdh4_1 ~]$ route -n; ping -c3 192.168.31.2; ping -c3 4.2.2.2; cat /etc/resolv.conf
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.31.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
PING 192.168.31.2 (192.168.31.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.31.217 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.31.217 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.31.217 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.31.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3003ms
pipe 3
connect: Network is unreachable
# Generated by NetworkManager


# No nameservers found; try putting DNS servers into your
# ifcfg files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts like so:
#
# DNS1=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DNS2=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DOMAIN=lab.foo.com bar.foo.com
```

Did I mess up with anything? If you need more data to point out the error, feel free to ask.

Comment: Are you able to ping the gateway by IP? Did you set DNS in `/etc/resolv.conf` (since you're doing static)?

Comment: @JoelDavis No, I did not set DNS.
I used this link http://lintut.com/how-to-set-static-ip-address-on-redhat-centos-and-fedora-linux/ However, I could not figure out what to set in resolv.conf. Can you help?

Comment: That might be the issue. I'd try setting the `nameserver` option in `/etc/resolv.conf` to your local DNS servers to see if it's just DNS resolution.

Comment: It's likely that you have no DNS server to resolve your names to IP addresses and/or your default route is not set. What does the output of `ip route ls`? Also if you're statically setting the IP then NetworkManager should not be managing this device, so set: `NM_CONTROLLED=no`.

Comment: What's the output of `route -n; ping -c3 192.168.31.2; ping -c3 4.2.2.2; cat /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: @AlaaAli have edited the question to include answer to your question.

Comment: Was the internet working before? What is the network adapter setting of your virtual machine? Is it set to NAT, Host-only or Bridged? I'm guessing it's set to NAT. If it's not, set it to NAT. If your host OS is Linux, look at the IP address of `vmnet8` from the output of `ifconfig`, it should be `192.168.31.1` (if Windows, open `cmd` and type `ipconfig` and look for VMWare Connection 8). If it's not `192.168.31.1` (let's say it's `192.168.56.1`), then change your Red Hat IPs to begin with `192.168.56` instead.

Comment: Also, restart Red Hat if you changed the VM network adapter to NAT (for some reason, sometimes it just doesn't apply immediately with me on VMware).